# Converting Objective-C struct arrays to Java

Tags: java, android, objective-c

I'm porting some Objective-C to Android.  The source app stores a lot of data in structure arrays and has some high performing methods to do lookups into the arrays and calculations on the result sets to provide near real time analysis of points on a graph as the user drags a pointer around the graph with their finger.  The calculation results are used to update values in various views surrounding the graph.

Here's an example which contain approx 7.5k structures.

```
structDataFeedReduced gFeedData[7662] = {
1233,@"",12.466667,26.166667,@"AARS",0,0,0,1.000000,-1,1,1,
6760,@"",15.816667,41.033333,@"DCTT",1,1,1,12.000000,-1,1,2,
8117,@"",44.016667,144.283333,@"SKDD",2,1,2,9.000000,-1,1,1,
8666283,@"WS",42.676666,40.006668,@"DLCC",3,2,3,-5.000000,-1,1,6,
...
...
...
};
```

My question is what is the best way to store this data statically in Java?

I've tried the following which are not high enough performance, either at load time or to provide data to the calculations at run time.

1. SQL Lite.
2. Reading from files stored in assets.
3. Storing statically as string arrays then processing them in initialisation into objects, using a class which mirrors the Objective-C structure (e.g. converting to int, bools, doubles etc from the string data)
4. Storing  in arrays.xml then processing them in initialisation into objects

Are there any other patterns I could try?  If there are none, then I'll favour 3 or 4 above as I'll sacrifice some loading and initialisation performance for good runtime response.

My backstop would be to push this down into native code using JNI.  Perhaps this is the only option that makes sense?

Thanks...

Comment: This looks like a prime place to use SQLite, as your data appears to be well-structured.

Comment: Thanks Richard but SQLLite is too slow for this problem,even with appropriate indices.  I can't show the entire complexity but there are often 5 or 6 redirections from one array into another to lookup data at the end of the tree. So you end up with SELECT blah FROM (SELECT foo FROM (SELECT bar FROM......) and the performance tanks.  I need to do several lookups a second to keep the UI fluid..

Comment: I think then you are doing it wrong. You could have an SQLite DB with just one table, that has the DataStructure of just your structure, and you could do a single `WHERE` clause to find the right row(s), then parse those back in your application. There should be no need for inner select statements in a well formed DB.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Are you suggesting denormalising the data?  E.g. if my structures are A, B, C, D and E, my rows look like this?  A1B1C1D1E1 ; A2B1C1D1E1 ; A3B1C1D1E1 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep that data as code.  You could define a `StructDataFeedReduced` class, then change your initialization code to:

```
static StructDataFeedReduced[] gFeedData = new StructDataFeedReduced[] {
    new StructDataFeedReduced(1233,"",12.466667,26.166667,"AARS",0,0,0,1.000000,-1,1,1),
    new StructDataFeedReduced(6760,"",15.816667,41.033333,"DCTT",1,1,1,12.000000,-1,1,2),
    ...
}
```

The constructor of `StructDataFeedReduced` can store the data in internal fields as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  I feel really stupid now, I simply didn't realise that one could call a class constructor in an array initialiser.  Works fine, thanks.